# Possible ways to automate post installation in lxc containers

Tags: ansible, lxc, proxmox

I'm having difficulty overseeing the possibilities of howto deploy an application on to a fresh LXC container.

Say I have a fresh LXC container, how would I provision it with my to-be deployed application?

1. Am I working against the intended use of LXC to start a new container for a new deployment? i.e., should I instead be looking at containers as long running just like a VM?
2. I'd like to use Ansible, but the methods of actually interfacing with a lxc container are limited. Modules bundled in Ansible allow you to start, stop, create a container, but actually installing software in the container is hard because a clean container does not allow to be accessed through SSH. Does anyone have success deploying with ansible to LXC without needing to write a lot of glue code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [ansible-lxc-ssh](https://github.com/chifflier/ansible-lxc-ssh) connection plugin:

> This plugin allows to use Ansible on a remote server hosting LXC containers, without having to install SSH servers in each LXC container.
>
> The plugin connects to the host using SSH, then uses lxc-attach to enter the container. This means the SSH connection must login as root, otherwise lxc-attach will fail.